# Splitting re.Match object type by words

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, attributes, python-re

I have this code that scans my emails and returns an important identifying number and its corresponding date. I am trying to split the number and the date into separate substrings separated by columns (ultimate plan is to get them all the info into a csv), but I get the following error: AttributeError: 're.Match' object has no attribute 'split'. Any help is appreciated. Here's my code:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+ [0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+')
matches = pattern.finditer(body)
for match in matches:
    matches.split()
```

I expect the output to look like the following:

```py
AAA111111, 1/1/2022
BBB222222, 1/1/2022
```

and so on. Goal is to turn it into a csv that I can import elsewhere

Also, here is what goes into body:

''
Thanks for following up. Here’s an update on your orders.

```
PUU128377 5/22/2023
PUN102938 11/1/2024
PUU012938 10/01/2025
```

Reach out with any further questions
''

New email with extended info

```
PUU128377 Line 20 Seq 1 5/22/2023
PUN102938 Line 100 Seq 8 11/1/2024
PUU012938 Line 120 Seq 4 1/1/2025
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely just put my expected output. what's sample (small)?

Comment: Can you put there the input as well?

Comment: @AndrejKesely my input is the first code block. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: I think Andrej meant to show us the value of `body` .

Comment: Also, maybe the problem is that you have a typo, match.split() instead of matches.split()

Comment: @anestv matches.split() didn't work either.. just put body in the question tho

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import re
import csv

body = """\
PUU128377 Line 20 Seq 1 5/22/2023
PUN102938 Line 100 Seq 8 11/1/2024
PUU012938 Line 120 Seq 4 1/1/2025
"""

pattern = re.compile(
    r"([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+) Line ([0-9]+) Seq ([0-9]) ([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)"
)
matches = pattern.finditer(body)

with open("data.csv", "w") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    writer.writerows(map(lambda m: m.groups(), matches))
```

This creates `data.csv` file:

```
PUU128377,20,1,5/22/2023
PUN102938,100,8,11/1/2024
PUU012938,120,4,1/1/2025
```

<sup>Edit: Updated answer with new input</sup>

Comment: If I extended the search thing to include more info, like extending the search field to r'[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+ Line [0-9]+ Seq [0-9] [0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+'   , do I need to make adjustments?
@AndrejKesely

Comment: @LaunchCoder33 Yes, use capturing groups `( ... )`, so for example `r'([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+) Line ([0-9]+) Seq ([0-9] [0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)'` or similar.

Comment: The original one works and produces a csv as expected, but the extended one returns an empty csv..

Comment: @LaunchCoder33 Without seeing your original input it's hard to make correct adjustment to regex pattern.

Comment: original input?

Comment: @LaunchCoder33 Yes, original body, where there are `Line` and `Seq` etc.

Comment: PUU128377 Line 20 Seq 1 5/22/2023

PUN102938 Line 100 Seq 8 11/1/2024

PUU012938 Line 120 Seq 4 1/1/2025

Here's the email that's getting scanned.. indented between each line in the email

Comment: @LaunchCoder33 Don't put the data into comments (there are not formatting). Can you edit your question and put it there (with correct formatting)?

Comment: just put in above

Comment: sweet! last question, can I adjust it so that if it doesn't have that info (like an email without the data) it will just skip over it while maintaining the rest of the code? because right now, whenever I make it go over multiple emails and one doesn't match, it returns a completely blank csv

Comment: @LaunchCoder33 You can use `re.findall` and use `if` to test if something was found - if not skip it. But that I leave to you ;)

Comment: could you spell it out exactly for me haha. my knowledge is very limited

Comment: overall, trying to make it so that everytime that pattern shows up, it'll add it to the sheet, and if nothing is in an email, it'll just skip over it. so the excel sheet would compile all occurences over 100 or so emails